# Get Input Caret Handle in Windows 8 (Metro) App

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a background process that retrieves the input caret position via GetGUIThreadInfo(). Here is a sample:

```
NativeMethods.GUITHREADINFO threadInfo = new NativeMethods.GUITHREADINFO();
threadInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(threadInfo)
NativeMethods.GetGUIThreadInfo(threadId, ref threadInfo);
IntPtr caretWindow = threadInfo.hwndCaret;
Int64 caretWindowInt = (Int64)caretWindow;
```

The above code works great on Windows 7 and below as well as any applications that run in the Desktop on Windows 8. When the focus is in a Windows 8 App (Metro) then "threadInfo.hwndCaret" is always NULL.

Does anyone know why this is happening or perhaps another way to get the Window Handle of the input control that has the input caret for Windows 8 (Metro) Apps?

Thanks!

Comment: WinRT apps don't use window handles.  Or carets.

Comment: So is there an alternative method to get input control that has is currently accepting input?